# remove query string on redirection htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, prestashop-1.5

I am unable to remove query string from redirection htaccess. I have tried a lott and googled als for this..but nothing seems to work

Here is my code:

First I tried this one but didnt worked :

```
Redirect 301  /my_page.aspx?ps=22.5000&pe=44.9900 http://www.mysite.com/35-new-items
```

Then I tried :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ps=
 RewriteCond %{QUERY)STRING{ (^|&)pe=4
 RewriteRule ^/?my_page\.aspx$ /35-new-items? [L,R=301]
```

But again this also didnt worked for me.

Then I tried this and as usual this also does not seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:my_page\.aspx)?\?p=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /35-new-items? [R=301,L]
```

Please help me !

I have to redirect old pages with different different query string values to the new one.
The old pages are in ASPX and the new pages are in PrestaShop.

So it is redirecting as http://www.mysite.com/35-new-items?ps=22.5000&pe=44.9900.

How to remove this part:

```
 ?ps=22.5000&pe=44.9900
```

from destination URL?

Comment: could you include generic `from_uri` and `to_uri`? Do you want to redirect a request with specific parameters rather than requests in general?

Comment: I want to redirect this page www.mysite.com/my_page.aspx?ps=22.5000&pe=44.9900 to www.mysite.com/35-new-items

Where ps="Any value" and  pe="Any value"  It is redirecting but with those PS and PE values(the query string). How to remove this query string upon redirection?

Comment: Can you provide your current .htaccess in your question?

Comment: Sorry Anubhava..cant paste my htaccess code but what I have done for this redirect is : Firstly I coded `Redirect 301 my_page.aspx /35-new-items` Then I used the below code given by the USER jacouh..see the Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better (tested on Debian/Apache2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(ps|pe)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?my_page\.aspx$ /35-new-items? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Didnt worked ! It is redirecting but with the same query string parameters

Comment: I have also cleared my browser cache. and I also tested on a different machine..but showing query string on the new url..:(

Comment: An outer module like PrestaShop complicates always things... it may have some additional rewrite. A question mark removes all query string see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: So it's redirecting, but with QUERY_STRING appended on the redirection URL? RewriteRule ^/?my_page\.aspx$ /35-new-items? [L,R=301] is working ? Have you others instructions in /.htaccess, and Have you /35-new-items/.htaccess file also?

Comment: What I have done for this is : Firstly I coded `Redirect 301 my_page.aspx /35-new-items`  Then I used your code for the query string. So both code is there in my htaccess

Comment: Please Comment Redirect 301 my_page.aspx /35-new-items with #, you'll see it works...

Comment: I have done this..but its not worked. i have also cleared my cache..but nt done..Please see my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is for google SEO so what I have done is because my page is redirecting so I have removed my query string value from the current url by using this smarty code

```
{$res=$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|regex_replace:"~\?[^/]++~":" "}
```

and used

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{Tools::getCurrentUrlProtocolPrefix()}{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$res}" />
```

so that canonization can be applied to avoid duplicate page content

Comment: We should wait for a '$smarty' expert to help us... Is this code action in PHP level?

Comment: This code is running under smarty TPL file. Actually the entire website is built on a CMS [http://www.prestashop.com/](PrestaShop)